# How to call variable in java

Tags: java, android

I created two java file, in one java file i get the android list view position in integer type position variable, how to call that position value in to another java file

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {     
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Play.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        int pos = position; //<------------ I assigned pos for position i need to call pos to another Play.class file
    }
```

Comment: Show both of your file

Comment: Can you please share the code of your first Java class and expand a little on what you intend to do with your classes? what's the specific purpose of your two classes?

Comment: Also may be you should actually learn the language via a book or a tutorial rather than jumping head on to code...

Comment: public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
 {     
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, Play.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  
  int pos = position;<-------- i assigned position to pos now i need to call this pos to another java file

Comment: @Pramoth Edit your question and post your code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ClassName cn = new ClassName(); // Creating instance of class
cn.variable;
```

If the variable is static you can call this way.

```
ClassName.variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let a java file File1.java in which you have the value of list view position :

```
public class File1{

    public File1(){
    yourMethodWhereListViewPositionAvailable();
    }
     private Integer listViewPosition;
     public Integer getListViewPosition(){
        return this.listViewPosition;
     }
     public void setListViewPosition(Integer listViewPosition){
        this.listViewPosition=Integer listViewPosition;
     }

     private void yourMethodWhereListViewPositionAvailable(){
        ............
        this.setListViewPosition(listViewPosition);
        ...................
     }
    }
```

In File2 you need the value of list view position , then do like this:

```
public class File2{
    .....................
    File1 file1 = new File1();
    file1.getListViewPosition();//You will get the value
   ..........................
}
```

Please let me know in case of help help or concern.